# Cannot Load Graphics Diagnostic into VS.net 2015 Graphics Analyzer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, directx, sharpdx

I have a solution in C#, VS.net 2015 Update 3 using the SharpDX 3.1 wrapper for DirectX11 (latest NuGet as of this date). The solution works fine, but I'd like to use the built-in VS.net Graphics Profiler to examine the performance.

I start the solution using the VS.net "Debug->Graphics->Start Graphics Debugging" and successfully capture screen shots which show in the diagnostics session. Clicking the link to View the Frame creates a .vsglog and subfolders in my temp folder and loads the Visual Studio Graphics Analyzer ("VSGA") with that .vsglog file.

The problem is that the VSGA always shows the error "The Graphics Diagnostics Engine has encountered a fatal error. Please try to reopen the doc..." which is logged in the Windows Event Viewer (so probably represents a genuine crash).

I have tried

- On two machines both running VS.net 2015 Community Edition with different graphics cards.
- swapping my application to using Warp (the software emulation DirectX11 layer).
- following other advice from Google I've restricted my application to using Feature Level 11 during the device creation.
- following other advice from Google using the DirectX Control Panel to force the VSGA to using Warp.
- I'm have marked VS.net and VSGA as "run as administrator".

I can only find one reference to this specific error message via Google, and this advises forcing the application to use DirectX 11 Feature Level 11, which I've done.

Im using Windows 10 with the optional Graphics Tools feature installed.

For info my Device Creation code is;

```
  private static void initializeDirect3DGraphicsDevice(System.Windows.Forms.Control winFormsControl, out Device device, out SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain sc)
    {
        // SwapChain description
        SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription destination = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,
            ModeDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.ModeDescription(
                winFormsControl.ClientSize.Width,
                winFormsControl.ClientSize.Height,
                new SharpDX.DXGI.Rational(60, 1),
                SharpDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
            IsWindowed = true,
            OutputHandle = winFormsControl.Handle,
            SampleDescription = new SharpDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0),
            SwapEffect = SharpDX.DXGI.SwapEffect.Discard,
            Usage = SharpDX.DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        // https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3102011/the-graphics-debugger-fails-to-load-on-gtx-1080
        // To enable graphics debugging we avoid featre levels above 11.
        SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel[] featureLevels = new SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel[]
        {
             SharpDX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Level_11_0
        };

        device = new Device(SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.Debug, featureLevels);
        using (SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1 factory = new SharpDX.DXGI.Factory1())
        {
            sc = new SharpDX.DXGI.SwapChain(factory, device, destination);
            factory.MakeWindowAssociation(winFormsControl.Handle, SharpDX.DXGI.WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device created with feature level " + device.FeatureLevel);


    }
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: "Im using Windows 10 with the optional Graphics Tools feature installed"